# What library I can use for parsing words in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, javacc

I'm trying to discover the type of words fitting they in a lot of categories (date, year, time, names, punctuation, email, etc). I was making my own code to detect this (and worked), but I found libraries like ANTLR and JavaCC.

What I want to do is a taks for these libraries? If yes, what I should use, if not, there is something I can use for this?

What are the recomendations? JavaCC, ANTRL, there is some more? I see that JavaCC generate some classes, but there are things that I don't want it does like tokenization.

Comment: well, if you have the option of using Jython, I guess you can use NLTK through that (and therefore use it in your java project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how powerful a parser you need. If you need something very powerful (such as JavaCC or ANTLR) go with them and don't spend too much time trying to make your own.

If you need something simple, then you can build a simple dictionary lookup parser with little more than [regular expressions in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) or maybe even [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) (if your example is very simplistic).

Comment: Yes, I think I need something powerful, I will for Natural Language Processing. I will be able to detect things like the examples I give in the question?

Comment: Well, natural language processing is a way deeper topic than simply finding dates, names, etc. NLP also has to do with not just the elements of the language, but the meaning and intent of the language. For NLP you'll probably want to look for API/libraries that are designed to approach that problem.

Comment: Yes, I studied a lot of NLP libraries, but they aren't what I'm searching. This taks of identifying is only a part of a major process I'm doing. I thin these libraries will help me more now.